# Python sys.path - appending PYTHONPATH

Tags: python

Before start
I have been trying to accomplish it for some time now, but I had no luck. I'm trying to create my own python package, which I will import the modules in it, in separate files in my project. I tried to add my project's directory to pythonpath via 'sys' but still the mod_wsgi do not recognize it:

```
import sys
sys.path.append('/var/www/')

from core.core import main
```

And when trying:

> ImportError: No module named core.core

Any help would be appreciated

Comment: Does your package have an `__init__.py` file in it?

Comment: What is the file structure of your project and package?

Comment: WTF.. I'll shoot myself in the head ASAP. My package did not have `__init__.py` file. Thanks guys.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you do not have the file `__init__.py` in your core folder, it will not be recognized as a package.

Therefore the solution is to add a file `__init__.py` in your core folder.

If you have already added the problem may be the absolute path ... the core folder that has absolute path:

1. /var/www/core
2. /var/www/YourProject/core

if the second option you have to do: `sys.path.append('/var/www/YourProject')`

Comment: You have used single quote at the beginning of your last code line, and a double quote at the end of that line.

Answer (score 0):

You need to explicitly set PYTHONPATH with you root directory.