# How do I use multiple settings file in Django with multiple sites on one server?

Tags: python, django, apache, amazon-ec2, mod-wsgi

I have an ec2 instance running Ubuntu 14.04 and I want to host two sites from it. On my first site I have two settings file, production_settings.py and settings.py (for local development). I import the local settings into the production settings and override any settings with the production settings file.

Since my production settings file is not the default settings.py name, I have to create an environment variable

```
DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE='site1.production_settings'
```

However because of this whenever I try to start my second site it says

```
No module named site1.production_settings
```

I am assuming that this is due to me setting the environment variable. Another problem is that I won't be able to use different settings file for different sites.

How do I start use two different settings file for two different websites?

Comment: Even after you fix Python module search path issues, careful of how you set DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE in the WSGI script file. See http://blog.dscpl.com.au/2012/10/requests-running-in-wrong-django.html for more details of why.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*Edit: I missed the apache tag on this so I've updated my answer accordingly*

Your problem is when running your Django app, site2, the python interpreter does not know about any of the modules in site1 because it's not listed in your PYTHONPATH.

I would highly recommend doing a short amount of reading up on how PYTHONPATH works before you continue: http://www.stereoplex.com/blog/understanding-imports-and-pythonpath

Now, there are many ways to resolve this, but we'll cover 3:

### Modify your apache virtualhost configuration for site2:

Be sure to read the docs here, first, for differences between mod_wsgi v1 and v2 but as you're running ubuntu 14.04, you should be using mod_wsgi v2 anyway.

https://code.google.com/p/modwsgi/wiki/ConfigurationDirectives#WSGIPythonPath

```
<virtualhost *:80>
    # your existing config directives
    WSGIPythonPath /path/to/site1
</virtualhost>
```

This has the advantage of not modifying any of your application code and, potentially having invalid directories in your PYTHONPATH when running site2 on your development machine.

### Append the path in your python code

[Python sys.path - appending PYTHONPATH](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13829526/python-sys-path-appending-pythonpath)

In your site2.wsgi file, before you start your Django app, add the following code.

```
import sys
sys.path.append('/path/to/site1')
```

Simple, and works.  This approach will also not cause you problems when moving between development (using manage.py runserver) and production.

### Create a simlink

[How to symlink a file in Linux?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1951742/how-to-symlink-a-file-in-linux)

Another simple choice is to simply simlink your production_settings.py into site2, and and then set your DJANGO_SETTTINGS_MODULE='site2.production_settings'

```
ln -s /path/to/site1/site1/production_settings.py /path/to/site2/site2/production_settings.py
```

If you're developing on a windows machine, this is probably the most problematic of the 3 approaches, so if you're pushing to the server using git or any other version control system, make sure to add your new simlink to your .gitignore file or your VCS's equivalent.

Comment: Except that PYTHONPATH environment variables in a user account aren't consulted by Apache/mod_wsgi. Necessary to use the configuration options of mod_wsgi to specify them, or do it in the WSGI script file by amending sys.path.

Comment: That is true, but there's nothing in his question about Apache.

Comment: The set of tags mentions 'mod-wsgi' and 'apache'. That is a very good indication they are using mod_wsgi.

Comment: @GrahamDumpleton you're totally right.. Don't know how I skipped over that.  I've updated my answer accordingly.

Comment: WSGIPythonPath can't be inside of VirtualHost. It can only go at 'server config' level in Apache configuration. If anyone is using mod_wsgi I would very much hope they are not using either version 1 or 2. Even version 3 is quite old now and has been on Linux distributions for years.