# python/django-extensions ImportError: No module named common.types_

Tags: python, django, python-extensions

I have managed to run a simple script located in a 'scripts' folder using 'runscript' from django-extensions. The technique is described here [1] (https://django-extensions.readthedocs.org/en/latest/runscript.html).
The script will run successfully as follows:

```
python manage.py runscript mysimplescript --script-args Testing 123
```

Should I now move the script to a sub-folder, then it appears I need to specify the full path to the sub-folder:

```
python manage.py runscript scripts.myfolder.mysimplescript --script-args Testing 123
```

I have written a python script which runs successfully when called directly from the command line ***within its own project folder***.  The complex script uses a number of additional scripts located within a plethora of sub-folders.

I now want to call this script within django using django-extensions' 'runscript', which means it's being invoked from the 'mysite/' folder where 'manage.py' is located. The script 'mycomplexscript.py' is not in the 'scripts/' folder but relocated to a separate 'myapps/' project folder, along with the sub-folders and scripts.

I've shown the structure below that includes 'mysite/' and some of the sub-folders/files within 'myapp/', notably the module 'myapp/common/types_':

```
mysite/
    manage.py
    mysite/
        __init__.py
        settings.py
        urls.py
        wsgi.py
    scripts
        __init__.py
        mysimplescript.py
    myapps/
        __init__.py
        mycomplexscript.py
        common/
            __init__.py
            comparison.py
            serialisation/
                __init__.py
                serialisation.py
                xml.py
            types_/
                __init__.py
                enum.py
```

Django-extensions requires that 'mycomplexscript.py' must incorporate a 'run()' function. Line #6 imports a class from one of the project sub-folders:

```
def run(*script_args):
    import os
    import sys
    import time
    from common.serialisation import XML
```

When calling the script, the error occurs because the module 'common.types_' cannot be located.

```
python manage.py runscript myapps.mycomplexscript --script-args Testing 123

/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/Django-1.9.2-py2.7.egg/django/core/ 
management/base.py:265: RemovedInDjango110Warning: OptionParser usage for  
Django management commands is deprecated, use ArgumentParser instead
RemovedInDjango110Warning)
Exception while running run() in 'myapps.mycomplexscript'
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "manage.py", line 10, in <module>
    execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)
File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/Django-1.9.2-py2.7.egg/django/core/ 
management/__init__.py", line 353, in execute_from_command_line
    utility.execute()
File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/Django-1.9.2-py2.7.egg/django/core/ 
management/__init__.py", line 345, in execute
    self.fetch_command(subcommand).run_from_argv(self.argv)
File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django_extensions-1.6.1-py2.7.egg/ 
django_extensions/management/email_notifications.py", line 63, in  
run_from_argv
    super(EmailNotificationCommand, self).run_from_argv(argv)
File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/Django-1.9.2-py2.7.egg/django/core/  
management/base.py", line 348, in run_from_argv
    self.execute(*args, **cmd_options)
File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django_extensions-1.6.1-py2.7.egg/ 
django_extensions/management/email_notifications.py", line 75, in execute
    super(EmailNotificationCommand, self).execute(*args, **options)
File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/Django-1.9.2-py2.7.egg/django/core/ 
management/base.py", line 399, in execute
    output = self.handle(*args, **options)
File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django_extensions-1.6.1-py2.7.egg/ 
django_extensions/management/utils.py", line 57, in inner
    ret = func(self, *args, **kwargs)
File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django_extensions-1.6.1-py2.7.egg/ 
django_extensions/management/commands/runscript.py", line 172, in handle
    run_script(mod, *script_args)
File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django_extensions-1.6.1-py2.7.egg/ 
django_extensions/management/commands/runscript.py", line 79, in run_script
    mod.run(*script_args)
File "/usr/tester/SwFact/isg_cid-system_test_current/my_site/myapps/ 
mycomplexscript.py", line 9, in run
    from myapps.common.serialisation import XML
File "/usr/tester/SwFact/isg_cid- system_test_current/my_site/myapps/ 
common/__init__.py", line 7, in <module>
    from comparison import Comparison
File "/usr/tester/SwFact/isg_cid-system_test_current/my_site/myapps/ 
common/comparison.py", line 7, in <module>
    from common.types_ import Enum
ImportError: No module named common.types_
```

The problematic Line #7 in 'comparison.py' is as follows:

```
from common.types_ import Enum
```

The error can be fixed if the ***full*** path to the root of the project is stated explicitly (+++):

```
from apps.common.types_ import Enum
```

This means that I would have to edit all the files and change the paths accordingly, which I'd like to avoid, if possible.
This link [2]:([Python: Referencing another project](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1476111/python-referencing-another-project)) describes the referencing another project from the command line, so I realize that this may nothing to do with the fact that I'm trying to do this by using django-extensions' 'runscript'.

Is there a way that I can resolve the path discrepancy, without having to modify all the files?  Would setting PYTHONPATH be the answer, as suggested here [3]:([How to use PYTHONPATH](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19917492/how-to-use-pythonpath))? I checked but 'echo $PYTHONPATH' currently doesn't return anything.

Apologies for the long-winded description.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: This is by design. You can't use partial and relative path from a script, python want the entire package

Comment: Is your packages compatible ? I had this problem when upgrading `django` from 1.8.9 to 1.9

Answer (score 0):

I tried sys.path.append("my/path") as recommended by link above and [4]:([Python sys.path - appending PYTHONPATH](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13829526/python-sys-path-appending-pythonpath)) and it seemed to work, so ***all*** the paths included in 'from' are now recognized without having to set the full path, as I described previously here (+++).

```
myapps/mycomplexscript:

# Procedures
def run(*script_args):
    import os
    import sys
    import time
    sys.path.append('/usr/tester/SwFact/isg_cid-system_test_current/   
    my_site/myapps')
    from common.serialisation import XML
    from common.task import Subscriber
    from test_ import TestHost
    from common.filesystem import Directory, File
    from common.tables import Column, Condition, CSVTable, Group
    from string import Template
    from datetime import date, time, datetime, timedelta
    from operator import itemgetter

    print script_args
```

So the result when running the script from 'mysite/':

```
python manage.py runscript myapps.mycomplexscript --script-args Testing 123

/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/Django-1.9.2-py2.7.egg/django/core/ 
management/base.py:265: RemovedInDjango110Warning: OptionParser usage for  
Django management commands is deprecated, use ArgumentParser instead
RemovedInDjango110Warning)
('Testing', '123')
```

It's not ideal to have to hard-code the path this inside the script, so perhaps it can be passed in as one of the arguments. The only problem with this is that imports appear at the top of the file, before any of the command line arguments are processed within the complex script however at least I know it works in principle.